# Best way to prevent collecting same elements in the dom tree?

Tags: javascript, dom

Have a need to append span element to DOM.

```
if (check smth...) {

    a = createElement('span');
    a.id = '_span';
    b = document.getElementById('container');
    b.appendChild(a);

}
```

What is the best way to do in "if" to prevent duplicating same element from dom tree ? It is kinda - "open the window and don't do it again until it were closed"

Comment: what is "d"  I see no d here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( document.getElementById( '_span' ) ) {
    // Your code where you're creating your element with id "_span"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an ID and before adding a new element check if there is an element with the given id.

```
if($('#element_id').length) {
  //do nothing, element is already in the dom
} else {
  //add element
}
```